# How to access a variable inside a function in an. ES6 module outside in js?

Tags: javascript, animation, es6-modules

I am trying to refactor my code and extract a fadeOut animation into an ES6 module. However, I need to access a property back in my main file. How can this be achieved.

I need to be able to access the `animation` variable inside the fadeOut function in the index.js to be able to listen to the animation and continue with the rest of my code.

```js
// index.js
import * as Utils from './utilities.js';

Utils.fadeOut(triviaContainerEl, '.trivia-item')
const animation = triviaDiv.animate(keyframes, options)
animation.addEventListener('finish', () => { ... } //Currently, I'm unable to access animation because the fadeOut fn is in another file
```

```js
// utilities.js
export function fadeOut(parentElement, selector) {
    const animatedElement = parentElement.querySelector(selector)
    const keyframes = [{
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        opacity: 0
    }]
    const options = {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'ease-out',
        delay: 500
    }
    const animation = animatedElement.animate(keyframes, options)
}
```

Comment: Just return the `animation` variable inside your `fadeOut` function.Then get it in your index.js as `const animation = Utils.fadeOut(triviaContainerEl, '.trivia-item');` Or pass down a callback as a third parameter and execute that within the `fadeOut` function.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with modules. It wouldn't work if the function was in the same file either.

Comment: @Reyno are you talking about something like this:    
````Utils.fadeOut(triviaContainerEl, '.trivia-item'); const animation = Utils.fadeOut(triviaContainerEl, '.trivia-item')````. If so, I'm am still unable to continue with the animation 'finish' listener